# MVC 2; Use a datepicker to input a date in a grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Has anyone successfully assigned a datepicker to a date field that is repeated in a grid?
Surely someone has done it before?
I find a problem with doing this is that the ID for each field in a row is repeated in the next row. So when I assign a date on the 4th row, I update the same field in the first row because their ID is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this... I just put this on my Edit View:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd. MMMM yyyy}", Model), new { @id = "datePicker" })%>
```

Via `new { @id = "something" }` you can control the HTML generated by helper method. This time I wanted the ID to be `datePicker` so that jQuery can be triggered accordingly.

---

And this is the ***jQuery Magic***:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"
rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datePicker').datepicker({
            altField: '#datePicker',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            altFormat: 'dd. MM yy',
            yearRange: '1900:2010'
        });
    });
```

Check [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) out for more jQuery Datepicker configuration settings.

Comment: This does not get round the problem of assigning a datepicker to a field in a grid. The point of the question is that in MVC when you create a grid, the ID of the field is the same on the fourth row as it is on the first. As a result, the wrong field gets updated.